# Types of objects that can be detected by the Cloud Vidion API

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Sorry if the question already exists.
Cloud Vision API can detect and extract multiple objects in an image using object localization.
Is the list of object names that can be detected publicly available? If so, I would like to know the web page where it is published.

LocalizedObjectAnnotations can be obtained in the following json format. (taken from the [official reference](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#localizedobjectannotation)).
I would like to know the type of "name".

```
{
  "mid": string,
  "languageCode": string,
  "name": string,
  "score": number,
  "boundingPoly": {
    object (BoundingPoly)
  }
}
```

Thank you for reading.